# Migrations in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am currently involved in a project where I am using Django 1.7 development version.I want to propogate changes that I make in my models (adding a field, deleting a model, etc.) into the database schema using "makemigrations" and "migrate" commmands.I added  a "age" field to one of the models in my application.

```
country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
postal_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=50, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
skype_name = models.CharField('Skype Username',max_length=50, blank=True)
age=models.IntegerField(max_length=25,blank=True)
```

When I use "makemigrations" command ,the output is like---"No changes detected".I guess that "makemigrations" is not  able to figure out the changes made to the schema.Any suggestions how can I make it work??

Comment: What exact command are you using? Are you including the app name?

Comment: "python manage.py makemigrations".No I haven't included the app name.

Answer (score 5):

If you are [adding initial migrations to an app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps), you must include the app name when using the `makemigrations` command.

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_label
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is the first time you are migrating that app you have to use:

```
manage.py makemigrations myappname
```

Once you do that you can do:

```
manage.py migrate
```

If you had your app in database, modified its model and its not updating the changes on makemigrations you probably havent migrated it yet.
Change your model back to its original form, run the first command (with the app name) and migrate...it will fake it. Once you do that put back the changes on your model, run makemigrations and migrate again and it should work.

Answer (score -3):

I have sometimes the same problem.
I manage to populate the change in the database by following :

> rm -rf your_app/migrations/*
>
> python manage.py migrate

if it doesn't work, consider a manual drop table before, if you don't have data in it.

it worked for me with django 1.7c1

Comment: Only suitable if you're working on your own or don't yet have any install other than your development one, as this deletes the main advantage of migrations which is to support database schema version control by creating incremental database update scripts.