# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'new_field' to userprofile without a default

Tags: python, django

I know that from Django 1.7 I don't need to use South or any other migration system, so I am just using simple command `python manage.py makemigrations`

However, all I get is this error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'new_field' to userprofile without a default;
we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

Here is models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

What are options?

Comment: I wanted to add that the problem occurs when you're changing existing table, not when you're creating a new one.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You need to provide a default value:

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='SOME STRING')
```

Comment: What if I need to have new_field a copy of a website field. How that should look? `default = website` does not do the job

Comment: You would want to first do the migration with a bogus default value, then create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to iterate through each record and set `new_field` to `website`.

Comment: default should be optional for CharField

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since the question specifically states "without a default".

Answer (score 134):

**If** you are in early development cycle and **don't care** about your current **database data** you can just remove it and then migrate. But first you need to clean migrations dir and remove its rows from table (django_migrations)

```
rm  your_app/migrations/*
```

Note: Don't delete _ _ init _ _ .py in the migrations folder.

```
rm db.sqlite3
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

**If** you previously created a superuser for Django's Admin web app then you might need to create the user again.

Comment: One more thing. You need to clean up migrations table
e.g.: `mysql -u[user] [database] -e "delete from django_migrations where app=[your_app]"`

Comment: This is the way. I think Django sucks at migration and model detection, etc. Want a major update for this.

Comment: I have deleted all files from migrations and deleted all rows from django_migrations and now  I am getting "django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration stories.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('sources', '0002_auto_20180903_1224')" when running migration.

Comment: Also be sure you don't delete the `__init__.py`  from migrations, or, you restore it afterwards, otherwise makemigrations won't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/46362750/1649917

Comment: `python manage.py sqlmigrate name_of_your_app nb_of_the_migration` is also required

Comment: This is my go-to way whenever it is not obvious what field Django is talking about. Sometimes it complains about defaults on fields that are not present in the model. In that case, I just nuke the entire directory and respective rows in the `django_migrations` table.

P.S. Obviously, this way is difficult to use when there is meaningful data to be preserved. In that case, it is a PIA.

Answer (score 51):

One option is to declare a default value for 'new_field':

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
```

another option is to declare 'new_field' as a nullable field:

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
```

If you decide to accept 'new_field' as a nullable field you may want to accept 'no input' as valid input for 'new_field'. Then you have to add the `blank=True` statement as well:

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
```

Even with `null=True` and/or `blank=True` you can add a default value if necessary:

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: «Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string.» —[Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

Answer (score 24):

In case anyone is setting a `ForeignKey`, you can just allow nullable fields without setting a default:

```
new_field = models.ForeignKey(model, null=True)
```

If you already have data stored within the database, you can also set a default value:

```
new_field = models.ForeignKey(model, default=<existing model id here>)
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are early into the development cycle you can try this -

Remove/comment that model and all its usages. Apply migrations. That would delete that model and then add the model again, run migrations and you have a clean model with the new field added.

Comment: And clean up migrations table django_migrations as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a#comment56426466_30456675 Or just use a GUI and delete required rows.

Answer (score 12):

You can't add reference to table that have already data inside.
Change:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

to:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, default = "")
```

do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

change again:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

do migration again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a workaround without having to make compromises such as dropping all existing data/migrations (yikes), requiring two separate migrations, or setting an unwanted default. Take these steps:

1. Add the new field to your model with `null=True`
2. `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> --name <migration_name>`
3. Change the new field to `null=False`
4. `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`. In this step, you'll see an option you may never have seen before! You want option 2: "Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)" [image]
5. Move the `migrations.AlterField` operation from the second migration into the first one, and add a manual migration to take care of the `NULL` values (if you don't take this step you'll get integrity errors like before), like so:

```py
def initial_display_names(apps, schema):
    Player = apps.get_model('my_app', 'Player')
    Player.objects.all().update(display_name='Cool Name')

def reversal(*args):
    """Reversal is NOOP since display_name is simply dropped during reverse"""


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0049_foo'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='player',
            name='display_name',
            field=models.CharField(help_text='name as shown in the UI', max_length=256, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(initial_display_names, reversal),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='player',
            name='display_name',
            field=models.CharField(help_text='name as shown in the UI', max_length=256),
        ),
    ]
```

6. Remove the second migration you made.
7. `python manage.py migrate <app_name>`

Answer (score 4):

If "website" can be empty than `new_field` should also be set to be empty.

Now if you want to add logic on save where if `new_field` is empty to grab the value from "website" all you need to do is override the save function for your `Model` like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, default='DEFAULT VALUE')
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, default='DEFAULT VALUE')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.new_field:
            # Setting the value of new_field with website's value
            self.new_field = self.website

        # Saving the object with the default save() function
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was early in my development cycle, so this may not work for everyone (but I don't see why it wouldn't).

I added `blank=True, null=True` to the columns where I was getting the error. Then I ran the `python manage.py makemigrations` command.

Immediately after running this command (and before running `python manage.py migrate`), I removed the `blank=True, null=True` from all the columns. Then I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` again. I was given an option to just change the columns myself, which I selected.

Then I ran `python manage.py migrate` and everything worked well!

Answer (score 2):

In new_file add the boolean property null.

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
```

after you run a `./manage.py syncdb` for refresh the DB. 
and finally you run `./manage.py makemigrations` 
and `./manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2):

Do you already have database entries in the table `UserProfile`? If so, when you add new columns the DB doesn't know what to set it to because it can't be `NULL`. Therefore it asks you what you want to set those fields in the column `new_fields` to. I had to **delete** all the rows from this table to solve the problem.

(I know this was answered some time ago, but I just ran into this problem and this was my solution. Hopefully it will help anyone new that sees this)

Comment: I haven't inserted rows into the table and still get this. I have to delete all migration history, clear migration table to change the model, as suggested by Tomasz.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method from Django Doc from this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#default

Create default and use it

```
def contact_default():
   return {"email": "to1@example.com"}

contact_info = JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

Answer (score 1):

I honestly fount the best way to get around this was to just create another model with all the fields that you require and named slightly different. Run migrations. Delete unused model and run migrations again. Voila.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with truncating the table of the model in question, you can specify a one-off default value of `None` in the prompt. The migration will have superfluous `default=None` while your code has no default. It can be applied just fine because there's no data in the table anymore which would require a default.

Answer (score 0):

What Django actually says is:

> Userprofile table has data in it and there might be `new_field` values
>   which are null, but I do not know, so are you sure you want to mark
>   property as non nullable, because if you do you might get an error if
>   there are values with NULL

If you are sure that none of values in the `userprofile` table are NULL - fell free and ignore the warning.

The best practice in such cases would be to create a RunPython migration to handle empty values as it states in option 2

> 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)

In RunPython migration you have to find all `UserProfile` instances with empty `new_field` value and put a correct value there (or a default value as Django asks you to set in the model).
You will get something like this:

```
# please keep in mind that new_value can be an empty string. You decide whether it is a correct value.
for profile in UserProfile.objects.filter(new_value__isnull=True).iterator():
    profile.new_value = calculate_value(profile)
    profile.save() # better to use batch save
```

Have fun!

Comment: I can't seem to find where this is written in the documentation. Can you post the link please

Answer (score 0):

In models.py

`class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default="some_value")`

You need to add some values as default.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I solved this Issue putting `null=True` in added model.
For example:

I was trying to add phone_number in the existing database module.

```
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I previously got this error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'phone_number' to customer
> without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to
> populate existing rows). Please select a fix:
>
> 1. Provide a one-off
>    default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for
>    this column)
> 2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

After putting

```
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'collegekhajagharapp':
  collegekhajagharapp\migrations\0002_customer_phone_number.py
    - Add field phone_number to customer
```

Comment: Multiple earlier answers, including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27036431) from 2014 already suggest using `null=True`. If you are going to answer old questions, please try not to post answers that are already given.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Model => Makemigrations Models => Migrate Models => Return Back the models => Makemigrations Models => Migrate Models

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to achieve this and:

- ...you are adding a `Foreign Key` field that is `NOT NULL`
- ...you have existing rows in the table
- ...and you don't want to create several migrations

A very minimal example to achieve this, is: Let's suppose you have an `Audio` model and you want it to have a `Directory` relationship, you would end up with something like this:

```py
import app.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0016_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Directory',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(default='New folder', max_length=200)),
                ('parent_directory', models.ForeignKey(default=None, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='directories', to='app.directory')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='audio',
            name='directory',
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                default=None, # <- ⚠️ This will fail because this field must have a value
                on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                related_name='files',
                to='app.directory',
            ),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

What I did is:

- In the same migration I created a data migration in which I create a temporary `Directory` model using `migrations.RunPython()`
- Then I use the `default=temp_first_folder["id"]` instead of `default=None`
- Finally, I run an extra code which will set the actual initial values.

So, yes, for a very brief moment it will have a temporary value, but immediately it will run a second data migration that will set the actual default values for you existing rows

This is how it looks

```py
import app.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

# This will be used later
temp_first_folder = {"id": None}

def create_temporary_folder(apps, schema_editor, temp_first_folder):
    DirectoryModel = apps.get_model("app", "Directory")
    temp_directory = DirectoryModel.objects.create(name="Fake folder")
    temp_first_folder["id"] = temp_directory.id

def initial_folders(apps, schema_editor):
    AudioModel = apps.get_model("app", "Audio")
    DirectoryModel = apps.get_model("app", "Directory")

    for audio in AudioModel.objects.all():
        actual_directory = DirectoryModel.objects.create(
            name=f"Folder {audio.id}",
        )
        audio.directory = actual_directory
        audio.save()

    # Finally, delete temporary fake folder
    DirectoryModel.objects.get(id=temp_first_folder["id"]).delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0016_audio_duration'),
    ]
    
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Directory',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(default='Nueva carpeta', max_length=200)),
                ('parent_directory', models.ForeignKey(default=None, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='directories', to='app.directory')),
            ],
        ),
        #  Let's create a temporary Directory
        #  It's important to use a lambda because that will allow you
        # to use the temp_first_folder variable
        migrations.RunPython(
            code=lambda apps, schema_editor: create_temporary_folder(apps, schema_editor, temp_first_folder),
            reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop
        ),
        # Look the "default" keyword, it's important that is a lambda
        # because that will allow you to use temp_first_folder variable
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='audio',
            name='directory',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=lambda: temp_first_folder["id"], on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='files', to='app.directory'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        # Run your code to set the actual default values
        migrations.RunPython(
            code=initial_folders,
            reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop
        ),
    ]
```

You could avoid the `temp_first_folder` variable by hardcoding the `default=1` and therefore assuming that when you create the Directory it will be the very first row, but I prefer to set a variable because that will ensure that everything works

Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

If the SSH it gives you 2 options, choose number 1, and put "None". Just that...for the moment.

Answer (score -2):

If your table is new and you dont care about the data follow below steps:

1. `Delete FROM public.django_migrations where app=<your_app_name>`
2. `Delete all migrations file from your project`
3. `DROP table <your_table_name>`
4. `python manage.py makemigrations`
5. `python manage.py migrate`

If you care about data, then add a default to your field

```
new_field = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='your_default_value')
```