# Error : "You are trying to add a non-nullable field"

Tags: python, django

I defined below model and getting

error : `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to videodata without a default; we can't do that`

models.py

```
class User(Model):
    userID = models.IntegerField()
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['userName']
        verbose_name = 'User MetaData'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users MetaData'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.userName)

class VideoData(Model):
    video = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    time  = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User_Video MetaData'
```

Where i am doing wrong????

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As the error says, your user field on VideoData is not allowing nulls, so you either need to give it a default user or allow nulls. Easiest way is to allow nulls.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User', null=True)
```

or have a default user

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User', default=<have your default user id here>)
```

Comment: On a database level, a foreign-keyed column requiring a default value is completely flawed and wrong. Django forces you to make your data architecture wrong. Also no support for composite foreign-keys. Such a damn shame.

Comment: I gave two options on how to solve the problem. Django isn't forcing a required default. I can think of plenty of situations where it would be acceptable to add a default foreign key.

Comment: Sad that this is the only viable solution.

Comment: @FeralessFuture I am curious about the sort of solution that you would think of as not "sad".

Comment: Noobie here--Why would this be a problem if you're just defining the model? If there is no pre-existing data, what does a FK default even mean?

Comment: @xtian The problem isn't when you are defining the models, it's when you actually create an instance of your model, it will need to know what to put in that non null field.

Answer (score 13):

I have run into the same problem with my OneToOneField. And, what I did was to delete all the migration files (which are under the directory of `migrations` under your app), and ran:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I don't know why, but it worked in my case. It won't hurt you to try what I wrote above.

Good luck!

Comment: This works well if it is for your local enviroment with meaningless data, but if it was for production you'd have to apply a default wanting it or not..

Comment: We can delete migrations for learning projects. In Live projects it would not be advisable to delete migration files. Should be some other solution as well.

Comment: -1. This is dangerous advice that will break your migrations and DB state. Resetting the migrations will accomplish the purpose, yes (because you are forcing django to think that the DB is empty) but it will lose the synchronization between the migration files and the DB migration state. If you changed your models without migrating before doing this, you will also find that django doesn't detect the changes anymore and now you're left with a broken model and consistency errors ready to appear at the next migration attempt. If you really want to do this, you have to nuke the DB and recreate it.

Comment: -1 As @soxwithMonica pointed out, deleting migration files should never be suggested as a solution. It is nothing but deleting your existing DB and recreating it - blank!.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to fix the same issue

1. Comment the foreign key reference in ***videodata*** and run the makemigrations and migrate
2. Add the model in *admins.py* and make a new entry in table
3. Now uncomment the foreign key reference and provide a **default=1** .Run make migrations and migrate
4. Remove the *default=1* in foreign key field.

Hope this helps.
This solution will work everytime you face these kinds of error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

1. change `requirement = models.ForeignKey(Requirement)` to `requirement = models.ForeignKey(Requirement, null=True)`
2. run makemigrations and migrate
3. change back `requirement = models.ForeignKey(Requirement, null=True)` to  `requirement = models.ForeignKey(Requirement)`
4. run makemigrations and migrate again.

I guess the rule of django-orm about foreignKey is:

1. allow foreignKey to be null when first create table
2. reject to add a foreignKey which is null, because the foreignKey of the data insert into table before will be null, which against programmer's will
3. allow to change foreignKey from not null to null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sometimes happens when you make a lot of changes in your models.py file (in my case It was related to an ImageField non-nullable field). Rather than field problems indeed. One solution in django 2.0.2 , python 3.6.4 , mysql 5.7.21

- Delete all files inside migrations folder `general_app/migrations/*.py`, except `__init__.py`, be careful.

You could check if the problem was fixed, if not:

- Repeat the above step, and
- Delete your database (e.g. in mysql `mysql> DROP DATABASE <name_db>`)
- Now create a new one with the same name `mysql> CREATE DATABASE <name_db>`.

These steps fixed the issue in my case. Now you could run without mistakes:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: If you want to do this you need to recreate the DB (backup with `dumpdata`), otherwise you will end with broken migrations. Note that recreating the DB may not be an option in production.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue:  ...non-nullable field 'user' to videodata...

model: Videodata

field: user

just add one more attr in the field user of the model Videodata: default=''

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when I use TextField().
I found my previous migration file somehow overwrites new fields.
Cleaning previous migration files before re-migrating happens resolve the issue.