# What is the default type for a user in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, database-migration

I have a MySQL database object that stores concerts that a User plans to attend on a certain date. Since each concert entry needs to be associated with a User, I added a foreign key field for User as an attribute of the Concert model. Here is the complete model:

```
class Concert(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    concert_name = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 120, blank = True, null = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
```

When I try to make migrations to the DB, I get a message saying: `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to concert with out a default;` s essentially saying that the already populated rows need to have a value. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a) which seemed to be addressing a similar issue, but the default value suggested in the solution is for a charfield and I don't think that would really apply in this situation. How should I go about setting the default value of the User object?

Comment: Pass it an integer; in the actual table, the column is  a foreignkey to the user table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `null=True`:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

Although if you look at your db actual model, you cannot see an actual Foreign Key, when you put `models.ForeignKey(User)` in your model you can see in your db a `user_id` with references, but the relation needed exists so you can make it's `null=True` as a default.