# How to add a file upload field in admin panel in Django 1.9?

Tags: python, django

I saw many tutorials on how to create a File upload field / Image Field using forms and templates. But I have a model called TestModel and I want to manage it with Django's default admin panel, how can I add a upload field to it ?

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers')
```

when I try `makemigrations`, result will be :

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'cover' to testmodel
>   without a default; we can't do that ( the database needs something to
>   populate existing rows). Please select a fix:  1) Provide a one-off
>   default now (will be set on all existing rows)  2) Quit, and let me
>   add a default in models.py Select an option:

What it the problem ?

Comment: Provide a one-off default or add a default in models.py

Comment: I tried with default=None but still the same result.

Comment: @Sayse what should I set as default value ?

Comment: [Very first google result for "You are trying to add a non-nullable field"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a). Please try to research your problem

Comment: @Sayse it is for char field ! what is default for Image Field ?

Comment: No, the accepted answer uses charfield but there are other answers in there that show other solutions. if not that then adding "imagefield" to the previously mentioned google result shows a page with a default. For further reference, see [ask] and [Is showing effort needed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288176/is-showing-effort-needed)

Comment: @Sayse Thank You, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's coming because of you did not put default value for cover field.
You have two option

1-a. It asking for default value ,select 1 and put dafault value, Ex-0,1

1-b.You can also select option 2 and change in your model field.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#imagefield

2. Clear testmodel table and then migrate.