# django table has no column named Exception

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

[Git Repository](https://github.com/brijesh-kalkani/My-Awesome-Cart)
Request to guide me on what to do.

I work on an e-commerce website with the help of Django. and I'm a beginner in Django
The following image provides a table of my database. It helps to add a product

[image]

Shows me an error in the browser. This error shows me when I add a product inside the admin panel. It helps to add a product but when I add the product the following error occurs.

[image]

An error occurred while migrating

[image]

Request to guide me on what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'new\_field' to userprofile without a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After first migrations,if you add any field that can not be null you must provide a default value. Your desc field is not nullable, so you must add `default='some_value'` inside your desc field.

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at here (Django Migrations Workflow)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#workflow)

I've seen your migrations folder on your Github repo and there was no sign of any of the fields you mentioned.

Every time you add fields to your models, you need to run following commands in terminal

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app name>
python manage.py migrate
```

These commands are going to modify your tables.

Please markdown your question instead of putting a picture from your code.
Check this out: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

---

EDIT:

In your Product model, there is a field named `desc`. You need to set a default value for it; Otherwise, you need to update the records in your database manually.

```
desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
```

After you do that, this error will happen to the `pub_date` field too. So, if your current Product objects in your database are not important, you can simply delete the database file `db.sqlite3` and delete your migrations file from this address `shop/migrations/0001_initial.py` and try the migration commands again.

Comment: @BrijeshKalkani Edit your question and put the error in it

Comment: I deleted the file and re-migration. But, there is an error adding the product.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the table ready and set up? Because the error says, that there is a table named shop_product, but it does not have a column named product_name.

So the structure of your table would get us closer to the solution of your problem.

Edit:

I have just seen, that you supplied your Git repo. I looked at the database and what I wrote above holds true. Your shop_product table has no columns. I did not look through your code to see if it would be set up automatically, but I suppose you were supposed to create the columns by hand, right?

Comment: You can see that I have created a product name column in the first image

Comment: Also in my code, there is a single table called product