# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'owner' to product without a default

Tags: python, django

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'owner' to product without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows

Comment: the error message mentioned exactly what the problem is, not sure what the question here is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'new\_field' to userprofile without a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a)

Answer (score 1):

Put in `null=True`, It will make your model field accept null values and also gives them `null` if you don't give them a value.

E.g:

```
owner = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

**OR**

you can put in a default for your model field

```
owner = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Some String')
```