# error while executing python manage.py makemigrastions

Tags: python, django

My Models Are:

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

class ExamCenter(models.Model):

```
cname=models.CharField(max_length=70)
city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

class Student(ExamCenter):

```
 name=models.CharField(max_length=60,default=False)
 roll=models.IntegerField(default=False)
```

1. when i Type python manage.py it generate an error but i cannot find it. the error is
   You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'examcenter_ptr' to student without a default; we can't do that
   (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
   2.remember It is a Multitable inheritance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'new\_field' to userprofile without a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a)

Comment: Hello , you can also define your filed like this;

examcenter_ptr = models.CharField( max_length = 60, null = False, blank = True )

Comment: I am interested in this line: ```name=models.CharField(max_length=60,default=False)```
How come ```default``` becomes False Here? Shouldn't it be filled up with any value or ```None``` instead?