# Not redirecting from createView form to Home

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am learning fresh django development. Working on a blog project I am facing a issue that, while publishing a new blog, that doesn't redirects to home/blogs page. I tried to manually to go home It says,

**OperationalError at /blog/
no such column: App_Blog_blog.author_id**

I tried to debug several times, searched in documentation can't get away with this author_id. These are my codes:

**Views.py**

```
class CreateBlog(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'App_Blog/create_blog.html'
    fields = ('blog_title', 'blog_content', 'blog_image',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        blog_obj = form.save(commit=False)
        blog_obj.author = self.request.user
        title = blog_obj.blog_title
        blog_obj.slug = title.replace(" ", "-") + "-" + str(uuid.uuid4())
        blog_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


class BlogList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'App_Blog/blog_list.html'
```

**Views.py of main project file**

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('App_Blog:blog_list'))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from App_Blog import views

app_name = 'App_Blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BlogList.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
    path('write/', views.CreateBlog.as_view(), name='create_blog'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_author')
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=264, verbose_name="Put a Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    blog_content = models.TextField(verbose_name="What is on your mind?")
    blog_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name="Image")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

**create_blog.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title_block %}
Write a Blog
{% endblock title_block %}


{% block body_block %}
<h2>Start Writing:</h2>
<form method="POST">
    {{ form | crispy }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Publish</button>
</form>
{% endblock body_block %}
```

**blog_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title_block %} Home {% endblock %}


{% block body_block %}

{% for blog in blogs %}
<h3>{{blog.blog_title}}</h3>
<h6>{{blog.publish_date}}</h6>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**Create Blog form:**

[image]

**Error showing on site:**

[image]

Comment: Can you also add the models code?

Comment: @Tamir Sorry missed that. updated now

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrated the database?

Comment: Have you migrated your models? I think that's the issue

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no didn't. I just tried that and its saying, 

"You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'author' to blog without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: @Tamir "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'author' to blog without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Are you populating an existing DB? Or are you working with a new one? Basically you can find an answer here: 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185687/you-are-trying-to-add-a-non-nullable-field-new-field-to-userprofile-without-a)

Comment: @Tamir I am working on a new project. I added default='id' and migrated then this shows up, "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'author'."

Comment: The best thing you can refer to is Django's documentation and understand how migrations and models work (This way you will actually learn what the issue is and not only a patch fix)