# Avoid makemigrations to re-create date field

Tags: django, django-models

Using Django 1.7, whenever I perform a `makemigrations`, I get a change on one of my models:

```
(venv) >> python manage.py makemigrations myapp

Migrations for 'myapp':
  0005_auto_20141206_1129.py:
    - Alter field date on observation
```

This is due to my Observation class using `datetime.today()`:

```
class Observation(model.Models):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today())
```

Is there an easy way to avoid creating migration files for this, but at the same time keeping the default of `today()` whenever an Observation is created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that each time this code is run the default changes to the current value of `today()`. That's because you're actually *calling* the function instead of passing it as a callable. Simply leave off the trailing `()` and you should be fine.

(Note that you should use `datetime.date.today`, since you want a `date` value, not a `datetime` value.)