# Should I be adding the Django migration files in the .gitignore file?

Tags: python, django, git

Should I be adding the Django migration files in the `.gitignore` file?

I've recently been getting a lot of git issues due to migration conflicts and was wondering if I should be marking migration files as ignore.

If so, how would I go about adding all of the migrations that I have in my apps, and adding them to the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Related: (1) [**Why** push migrations to VCS? (`stackoverflow`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376092/why-there-is-need-to-push-django-migrations-to-version-control-system); (2) Tips about managing conflicts: [Is it really important to save django's migrations in a version control system? (`dev.to`)](https://dev.to/simo97/is-it-really-important-to-save-djangos-migrations-in-a-version-control-system--5d03); (3) Info on _squashing_ migrations: [How do you guys manage git + migrations? (`reddit`)](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/msm26e/how_do_you_guys_manage_git_migrations/)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Quoting from the [Django migrations documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/):

> The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are designed to be committed to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines.

If you follow this process, you shouldn't be getting any merge conflicts in the migration files.

When merging version control branches, you still may encounter a situation where you have multiple migrations based on the same parent migration, e.g. if two different developers introduced a migration concurrently. One way of resolving this situation is to introduce a *merge_migration*. Often this can be done automatically with the command

```
./manage.py makemigrations --merge
```

which will introduce a new migration that depends on all current head migrations. Of course this only works when there is no conflict between the head migrations, in which case you will have to resolve the problem manually.

---

Given that some people here suggested that you *shouldn't* commit your migrations to version control, I'd like to expand on the reasons why you actually *should* do so.

First, you need a record of the migrations applied to your production systems. If you deploy changes to production and want to migrate the database, you need a description of the current state. You can create a separate backup of the migrations applied to each production database, but this seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Second, migrations often contain custom, handwritten code. It's not always possible to automatically generate them with `./manage.py makemigrations`.

Third, migrations should be included in code review. They are significant changes to your production system, and there are lots of things that can go wrong with them.

So in short, if you care about your production data, please check your migrations into version control.

Comment: We, a team of developers, have exactly the same problem, too. If one member performs `makemigrations some_app`, not only the models under that member's control will be affected, but also other related models will be affected, too. That is, the migrations files (00*_*) in other apps will be changed. And that causes many conflict problems during pushing to or pulling from GitHub. Since currently our system is not ready for production, we just `.gitignore` the migration file. We still don't know how to solve it when the system goes production. Does anybody has any solutions?

Comment: So if I good understand you have to pull the migrations from your project. When you change something you have to do a local makemigrations. Push it again and the buildserver will do the migrate? (Very important ofcourse everyone has the good versions)

Comment: we never use django migrations. everyone connects to a central test database, if a change is needed, it is done manually at the db level when needed. This method works good if the system is mature enough when it won't need many database schema updates.

Comment: @yltang52 We are currently trying to figure it out as well, can you share any insights? I think once you go to production you have no choice but to maintain those migrations to allow for easier patches and overall easier version control.
I also wonder what you do with Initial state data (like settings stored in db). How do you maintain them?

Comment: I don't think you should put migrations files into repo. It will spoil the migration states in other person's dev environment and other prod and stage environment. (refer to Sugar Tang's comment for examples). Tracking models file is sufficient.

Comment: i down voted this answer. i explained in my comments.

Comment: @Sean Noted.  What you are suggesting doesn't work.  And do you really think an answer suggesting to follow the documented process is not helpful?

Comment: I will add that sometime makemigrations doesn't work flawlessly. Case in point, I removed a model and got InnoDB errors trying to migrate from the auto makemigrations file. Instead, I had to first remove all fields from the model, makemigration, then remove the model, and makemigration again. So I'm leaning towards checking them in. Any better alternative?

Comment: @RandyTang, gurel_kaynak, Diansheng : do not ignore migrations!!! migration conflicts must be resolved, not ignored. Use a proper git flow instead. Read answer below plz. Also this answer is good, but merge conflicts can happen and must be resolved.

Comment: @DanielDubovski this is very late, but you add those Initial state data like settings through a migration. It's also documented in [providing initial data with migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-migrations).

Comment: link does not work

Answer (score 43):

You can follow the below process.

You can run `makemigrations` locally and this creates the migration file. Commit this new migration file to repo.

In my opinion you should not run `makemigrations` in production at all. You can run `migrate` in production and you will see the migrations are applied from the migration file that you committed from local. This way you can avoid all conflicts.

**IN LOCAL ENV**, to create the migration files,

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Now commit these newly created files, something like below.

```
git add app/migrations/...
git commit -m 'add migration files' app/migrations/...
```

---

**IN PRODUCTION ENV**, run only the below command.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: In my opinion,  migrations file should only be part of the repo once the app deployed. That counted as initial migrations. If the app still in heavy development, we can safely ignore it. But once it goes live. That's it! That's the sign that migrations should be put into repo. Every other members then need to follow this migrations and put theirs when needed

Comment: Very good point to only run `migrate` and NEVER `makemigrations` for committed migrations. Never thought of that.

Answer (score 23):

Quote from the 2024 docs, Django 5.0. (two separate commands = `makemigrations` and `migrate`)

> The reason that there are separate commands to make and apply
> migrations is because you’ll commit migrations to your version control
> system and ship them with your app; they not only make your
> development easier, they’re also useable by other developers and in
> production.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 18):

### **TL;DR: commit migrations, resolve migration conflicts, adjust your git workflow.**

Feels like you'd need to adjust your **git** workflow, instead of ignoring conflicts.

Ideally, every new feature is developed in a different branch, and merged back with a **pull request**.

PRs cannot be merged if there's a conflict, therefore who needs to merge his feature needs to resolve the conflict, migrations included. This might need coordination between different teams.

It is important though to commit migration files! If a conflict arises, [Django might even help you solve those conflicts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#version-control) ;)

Comment: That's the right answer. An operational versioning system workflow seems to be implicit in the django documentation but it's fundamental.

Answer (score 5):

I can't imagine **why** you would be getting conflicts, unless you're editing the migrations somehow? That usually ends badly - if someone misses some intermediate commits then they won't be upgrading from the correct version, and their copy of the database will be corrupted.

The process that I follow is pretty simple - whenever you change the models for an app, you also commit a migration, and then **that migration doesn't change** - if you need something different in the model, then you change the model and commit a new migration alongside your changes.

In greenfield projects, you can often delete the migrations and start over from scratch with a 0001_ migration when you release, but if you have production code, then you can't (though you can squash migrations down into one).

Comment: Great point about starting over from scratch with 0001 for release.

Answer (score 5):

The solution usually used, is that, before anything is merged into master, the developer must pull any remote changes. If there's a conflict in migration versions, he should rename his *local* migration (the remote one has been run by other devs, and, potentially, in production), to N+1.

During development it might be okay to just not-commit migrations (don't add an ignore though, just don't `add` them). But once you've gone into production, you'll need them in order to keep the schema in sync with model changes.

You then need to edit the file, and change the `dependencies` to the latest remote version.

This works for Django migrations, as well as other similar apps (sqlalchemy+alembic, RoR, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Gitignore the migrations, if You have separate DBs for Development, Staging and Production environment. For dev. purposes You can use local sqlite DB and play with migrations locally.
I would recommend You to create four additional branches:

1. Master - Clean fresh code without migrations. Nobody is connected to this branch. Used for code reviews only
2. Development - daily development. Push/pull accepted. Each developer is working on sqlite DB
3. Cloud_DEV_env - remote cloud/server DEV environment. Pull only. Keep migrations locally on machine, which is used for the code deployment and remote migrations of Dev database
4. Cloud_STAG_env - remote cloud/server STAG environment. Pull only. Keep migrations locally on machine, which is used for the code deployment and remote migrations of Stag database
5. Cloud_PROD_env - remote cloud/server DEV environment. Pull only. Keep migrations locally on machine, which is used for the code deployment and remote migrations of Prod database

Notes:
2, 3, 4 - migrations can be kept in repos but there should be strict rules of pull requests merging, so we decided to find a person, responsible for deployments, so the only guy who has all the migration files - our deploy-er. He keeps the remote DB migrations each time we have any changes in Models.

Comment: "_Keep migrations locally on machine_" and what happens when that machine goes down? (With database being safe) The migration files will be lost with no way to know what exactly they were...

Answer (score 1):

You should think of migrations as a version control system for your database schema. **makemigrations** is responsible for packaging up your model changes into individual migration files - analogous to commits - and migrate is responsible for applying those to your database.

The migration files for each app live in a “migrations” directory inside of that app, and are **designed to be committed** to, and distributed as part of, its codebase. You should be making them once on your development machine and then running the same migrations on your colleagues’ machines, your staging machines, and eventually your production machines.

golden rule : Make once on dev and migrate on all

Answer (score 0):

Having a bunch of migration files in git is messy. There is only one file in migration folder that you should not ignore. That file is **init**.py file, If you ignore it, python will no longer look for submodules inside the directory, so any attempts to import the modules will fail. So the question should be how to ignore all migration files but **init**.py? 
The solution is: 
Add '0*.py' to .gitignore files and it does the job perfectly.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: don't know if this still holds true for Python versions above 3.8... anyone?

Answer (score -2):

Committing your migrations is just a recipe for disaster. Because the migrations are somewhat or a chain that can be traced back, if you have dependences from a former migration e.g a pip module which you used at some point in your project lifecycle and then stopped using. You might find bread crumbs of such dependences in your migrations thread and you have to manually remove these imports from the migrations file.

Verdict, except you are a god tier Django dev, probably avoid adding migrations to your commits.

Answer (score -3):

**Short answer**
I propose excluding migrations in the repo. After code merge, just run `./manage.py makemigrations` and you are all set.

**Long answer**
I don't think you should put migrations files into repo. It will spoil the migration states in other person's dev environment and other prod and stage environment. (refer to Sugar Tang's comment for examples).

In my point of view, the purpose of Django migrations is to find gaps between previous model states and new model states, and then serialise the gap. If your model changes after code merge, you can simple do `makemigrations` to find out the gap. Why do you want to manually and carefully merge other migrations when you can achieve the same automatically and bug free? [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/) says,

> They*(migrations)*’re designed to be mostly automatic

; please keep it that way. To merge migrations manually, you have to fully understand what others have changed and any dependence of the changes. That's a lot of overhead and error prone. So tracking models file is sufficient.

It is a good topic on the workflow. I am open to other options.

Comment: This will only work for toy projects, and has many downsides.  It immediately stops working for hand-written migrations, for services using multiple ephemeral app servers (i.e. _any_ serious application) and for apps consisting of many Django apps each with their own migrations.  And I don't understand what you are referring to with "manually merging migrations" – `manage.py makemigrations --merge` works fully automatically for me.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, I was indeed working on small but serious applications. And it works for me.