# Stopping ignoring migration files in git for a Django Project

Tags: django, git, migration, gitignore, migrate

My team has had the Django migration files in .gitignore , and so hasn't been committing these files. Instead we've been making migrations on our production server. We discovered that this is not the recommended practice (upon encountering [Should I be adding the Django migration files in the .gitignore file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035119/ignoring-migration-files-in-git-in-a-django-project) ). Would it cause problems to - at this point in time - remove migrations from .gitignore, makemigrations on the development machine, commit, push, and apply the migrations on the production server? If so, how can we get around these problems?

This question is motivated largely because we need to apply a custom migration that we partially wrote ourselves. (As such there's actually an additional step between making migrations on the development machine and committing them, namely adding in our custom code to the migration file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to copy over all the migrations from production server to your repo then commit them. This is most likely a manual process because your production server is the only place that tracks all migrations. You don't need to worry about how to migrate your production server because it keeps the original copy. However, all these should be done before any new migrations are added and applied.

After all is fixed, you should create new migrations in your local dev environment, add to git and push your migration to production then apply the migration. Remember to have your CI or something else check for duplicate migration files.