# Stuck in a django migration IntegrityError loop: can I delete those migrations that aren't yet in the db?

Tags: python, django

So, I committed and pushed all my code, and then deployed my web application successfully. Then, I added a new model to my 'home' app, which (for a reason I now understand, but doesn't matter here), created an `IntegrityError` (`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "foo" violates foreign key constraint "bar"`). I ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`, which causes the the `IntegrityError`.

However, even if I remove all of my new model code(so that git status comes up with nothing), the IntegrityError still happens. If I connect to my db via a different python instance and download `select * from django_migrations;`, the latest db migration: **0020** there is eight migrations away from my latest local `home/migrations` migration file: **0028**.

--> My question is: is it safe for me to delete my local **0021-0028** migration files? Will this fix my problem?

Comment: what version of django are you using? Also when exactly do you get this error? When you run migrations?

Comment: version `1.10`. Sorry, should have been more clear about that. I got the error after running `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: If your migrations wasn't applied it safe to delete them. Because they can be easily recreated with `makemigrations`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I had tried running `python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate` both again, but error didn't go away. However, deleting the migrations and then doing that worked!

Comment: Don't forget to add this migrations to git repo.

Comment: Migrations are supposed to be added to git? Hrm. I had them all in my gitignore.

EDIT: they should be in git (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035119/should-i-be-adding-the-django-migration-files-in-the-gitignore-file)
OK, doing that :) - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't applied your migrations to db, it is safe to delete them and recreate them.

Possible reasons of why you run into this error are:

1. You deleted your model code but, when you run `migrate` it reads your migration files (which has information about your deleted model) and tries to apply migration operations. If you didn't run `makemigrations` command after you've deleted your model, migration system won't be able to detect your changes and will think that your model is still there.
2. Even if you've run `makemigrations` after you've deleted your model there'll be dependency issues in your migrations files, because the new migration files will depend on old ones (with which you had problems)

That's why we can say that it is safe to delete them, if they haven't applied, but at the same time you should be careful with your migration dependencies.

This [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#history-consistency) information maybe useful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I crossed my fingers, backed my local 0021-0028 migration files, and then deleted them. **It worked**. I think they key is that the migration files were not yet in the database yet, but not 100% sure. +1 if anyone can answer further for clarification.

Comment: yes, the migrations had not been applied for whatever reason