# Django Migrations are not Migrating on production

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, database-migration, django-migrations

I am using MySql DB,I am having some problems with the migrations.When I am running `python manage makemigrations` it creates a migration file with the old field migrations also,and when I run `python manage migrate` I get "No migrations to apply",but when i check the db,fields are absent.I had this problem recently but --fake worked for it,Now when I am faking it also gives "No migrations to apply".I am working On production server so I don't think deleting migration files and resetting db is a good solution.Maybe someone can help me with that,Thank in advance!

This is the migrations file which it created for me now,I only added cancellation_note and Iban fields now.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auths', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='bank_account_iban',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='bank_account_name',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='bank_account_name_on_card',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='social_media_account',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='cancellation_note',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customuser',
            name='iban',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='payze_saved_cards',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('CardToken', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('CardMask', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('CardBrand', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('CardCountry', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('CardHolder', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('ExpirationDate', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: What's the number of your latest migration for this app in django_migrations table? Is it the same as name of migation file you have provided? Is it the same as number in front of migration file you have provided?

Comment: @PTomasz It is 75 in django-migrations table,migration file name is 0002_remove_customuser_bank_account_iban_and_more.py

Comment: Is it possible that you run migration on your production db and then instead of creating new migration after changes you edited old one?

Comment: No,cuz I am not directly working with production db

Comment: 75 is pk of row in this table, what's the name in table? Does it also starts with 0002 as your created migration file in app?

Comment: No,it is 0008_remove_customuser_iban.But I also have 0002_remove_customuser_bank_account_iban_and_more which is the name of the migration file now and it's pk is 66

Comment: That's a weird one. Is it working on your local development? Like when you delete all tables in app database and then try to setup it from the start using migrations?

Comment: I have deleted db and migration files and migrated it one more time but it worked for me :),But now I don't want to do that cuz project is in the production and it will not be the best solution

Comment: My best guess is that your migration table in production is somehow corrupted. I think that deleting all rows from that table and running migrate --fake should fix your issue, but it's impossible for me to be sure. You could try dumping your production db on your local machine and running it there to see if it will help you

Comment: By migration table I meant django_migrations

Comment: Iam testing that migratons on local for my local base and it does the same thing

Comment: @PTomasz I tried the solution you provided,But it is not adding the field in the db :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: btw,I deleted all migration files and db,--fake didn't work,but the plain migrate worked.If anybody has any ideas why is it happening please HELP!

Comment: @Rafaell444, its not a solution to your issue, instead it help how to do migrations in production, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035119/should-i-be-adding-the-django-migration-files-in-the-gitignore-file