# Forgot Admin Password on Postgres (Windows Installation), can't reset

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I have a Windows PostgreSQL installation.

According to some posts, there is no default password set for the 'postgres' user yet I can't connect using an empty password string.

I'm receiving this exception when I try to connect:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The most relevant tip was this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943227/1005607

```
Open  pg_hba.conf  
Change md5 -> TRUST  
then restart PgAdmin.
```

I tried that and restarted PGAdmin but it still asks me for the password when I try to connect:

[image]

The task manager in Windows shows some PostgreSQL processes are running. I can't switch them off.

I have tried this and it failed:

```
pg_ctl restart

ERROR: 
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset

psql.exe postgres
Password: (none)
ERROR:
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

How can I reset the default password for user 'postgres'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on AK47's answer and some additional info I fixed it by doing the following,

1) Stop Postgres if currently running, command line below. Need to give it the 'data' dir. In my case C:\PostgreSQL\data

```
pg_ctl -D C:\PostgreSQL\data stop
```

2) Edit the file `pg_hba.conf` (it's also in the \data dir) as follows:

As AK40 wrote, c**hange all MD5 references to trust** , e.g.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

3) Now run

```
psql -U postgres
```

4) In the PG Command Prompt that appears type,

```
ALTER USER Postgres WITH PASSWORD '<newpassword>';
```

5) Save this by typing `wq` enter to exit the PG Prompt

6) Now start Postgres

```
pg_ctl -D C:\PostgreSQL\data start
```

7) Might want to revert the `MD5 -> Trust` change later in the `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: I'm going to update my answer based on some of the details in this which I left out

Comment: Would be nice to precise that all "md5" which address a local address have to be changed. It could be dangerous to trust every connexions even those coming from outside the server.

Comment: How do you expect `psql -U postgres` to work if the server is stopped?

Comment: That's what starts back the server

Comment: how can I use the first command if my postgres installed in "Program Files" directory?

Answer (score 4):

Update your `pg_hba.conf` file to allow for trusted local connections

```
[root@server] vim pg_hba.conf
>> local all all         trust
```

then restart your PostgreSQL server

```
[user@machine] pg_ctl -D C:\PostgreSQL\data restart    (Windows)
[root@server] service postgresql restart            (Linux)
```

at this point you can connect to your server as postgres user using a local connection without the need to enter a password (omitting the `-h` parameter when calling the `psql` command will use a local connection - if you pass `-h` then this will match the line `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 <method>` in your `pg_hba.conf` file)

```
[root@server] psql -U postgres
```

You can then alter the postgres user role and set the password to whatever you like using the following command in the `psql` terminal

```
[psql] alter role postgres password <new_password>;
```

Once this is done you can restart your PostgreSQL server again

```
[user@machine] pg_ctl -D C:\PostgreSQL\data restart     (Windows)
[root@server] service postgresql restart             (Linux)
```

and at this point your password should be changed to the new password

Comment: I'm on Windows. I edited the file, but there's no "service postgresql restart".

Comment: [See this answer for how to restart PostgreSQL on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629963/how-to-start-postgresql-on-windows)

Comment: Bruh it says "Windows"

Comment: @Kloody see the accepted answer. The author posted a solution based on this

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I couldn't use Postgres in the CLI on my windows machine but I managed to trace down where the passwords were stored via

```
%APPDATA%\PostgreSQL\pgpass.conf
```

NB: You must have selected store password option when creating a server or database in the pgAdmin.

I hope this helps. Thanks.