# python manage.py makemigrations gives No changes detected?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just clone exiting project from github, and **dump mysql database in my local machine**. Every thing is working fine. I made some changes in myapp/model.py, like add new tables. After that when run
                          **1.** `python ./manage.py makemigrations myapp`.   Then it makes migration files like

```
Migrations for 'myapp':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model AndroidRegkey
    - Create model ApkVersion
     ....................... 
     .......................
```

2. `python manage.py migrate myapp` it gives following message

   ```
   Operations to perform:
     Apply all migrations: myapp
   Running migrations:
     No migrations to apply.
   ```

This is the first time migration on my local machine. I already have database. But after Adding new models in model.py first time **it does not apply any migration to data base, why?**

I also go this link [stack-over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912173/django-1-7-makemigrations-not-detecting-changes) but not working.

When I ran `python manage.py migrate --list`  Getting following result.

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
intracity
 (no migrations)
mailer
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150720_1433
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Comment: Run `python manage.py migrations --list` to see the status of your migrations.

Comment: Getting `Unknown command: 'migrations'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.` When I ran `python manage.py migrations --list`

Comment: sorry, `python manage.py migrate --list`

Comment: @rix please see updated question

Comment: So you can see that your migrations have been applied.  Hence the no migrations to apply msg.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply migrations, the migrations that have been applied are stored in the database. They will also be exported to your database dump. So your database should already be in the correct state after you import the data locally. Django looks at the relevant table, sees you're up to date, and takes no further action.